# How delete documents from a Firestore collection with a 'where' clause in Web v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to complete the following code:

```
const myCollection = collection(db, 'myCollection');
const mycollectionQuery = query(myCollection, where("field1", "==", "xyz"));
myCollectionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     deleteDoc(?);
});
```

Advice on what to supply inside the `deleteDoc` call would be much appreciated. I was pretty confident it would be `doc.id`, but this returns a "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_delegate' in undefined" error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V9, the `deleteDoc()` method takes a DocumentReference, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#deletedoc).

As you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshotforeach) of your `forEach()`, the `doc` variable will be a QueryDocumentSnapshot, that is a specialization of DocumentSnapshot. It means that, if you want to retrieve the DocumentReference for your `doc`, you just need to reference to it via `doc.ref`.

In other words, to delete the document you'll need to do this:

```
myCollectionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     deleteDoc(doc.ref);
});
```

Comment: @GP : Many thanks for the prompt response. That did the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is how you delete a document from cloud firestore:

```
deleteDoc(doc(db, "reference"))
```

So, the complete code is:

```
const myCollection = collection(db, 'myCollection');
const mycollectionQuery = query(myCollection, where("field1", "==", "xyz"));
myCollectionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     deleteDoc(doc(db, doc.ref));
});
```